# Is it possible to get Wordpress to import and display featured images from a third-party RSS feed?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a client with two active Wordpress sites (let's call them A and B). I am currently redesigning site A. Per client request, site A should display on its homepage an RSS feed block of site B's news feed. This includes the featured images from posts in site B's feed. However, I cannot find any way to get these featured images to show up on site A. Wordpress admin panel gives no option in the RSS feed block settings to show featured images; a lot of googling has turned up nothing on how to code this as a default for the RSS feed block in the theme itself (which would be preferable in this case to hard coding the RSS feed import in the theme file).

I wondered if the problem might be on site B's side and requested that the client contact site B's team and make sure they had enabled featured image sharing for their RSS feeds, and some days later was assured that this had been done. However, nothing seems to have changed on my end - the images are still not showing up on site A and I can't even find, say, hidden links to them when using the inspector tool (or anything else which might indicate the images are present but not visible due to CSS etc).

I'm fairly new to Wordpress and this seems like something which would be done commonly and have a straightforward solution, but I'm at a loss. Wordpress's [own docs](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/rss-block/) for the RSS block don't mention a possibility of importing images. Is it even possible to customise the block in this way? Will the whole RSS feed section have to be hard coded into the theme files?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RSS Block doesn't support images, but you can try using a plugin. Both [WP RSS Retriever](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-retriever/) and [WP RSS Aggregator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/) support images.

I also recommend manually inspecting the RSS feed to ensure that the featured images are included.

Comment: Alright, good to know! I'll try doing it with a plugin.